# Wysiwg Editor of Advanced Custom Field is not giving output with proper HTML Tags

Tags: wordpress

I have Wordpress: Version:4.8
Plugin: Advanced Custom Field:Version 4.4.11

I have Created Custom Field: Details
The Field Type: Wysiwg Editor

Source Code Data:

```
<p>From The Architect - The Split House negotiates a complex range of conditions typical of emerging coastal developments. New houses for ‘downsizers’ in a suburban mode, paved driveways and letterboxes prevail, vying for the expansive views to Port Philip Bay, and backed by the relatively wild, coastal woodland of Mt Martha Public Park. The Split House provides a range of spatial relationships to its site and the broader territory that carefully balances the owners’ desire for privacy and engagement with their surrounds. The house comprises two relatively simple volumes linked by a splayed stair that also acts as a seating area for people to gather, listen to music, sit in the sun. Occupying separate levels that follow the natural contours of the site, the two pavilions provide a separation between the upper, main living/master bedroom zone and rumpus room/guest bedrooms below. Through the curation of windows and doors a range of direct and indirect connections to the landscape provide multiple opportunities for occupation throughout the year. Smaller elements, such as integrated seating, stairs and study nooks provide spaces for quiet contemplation, juxtaposed with larger communal areas for family and friends to come together.</p>
<p>The award-winning house was designed for a couple who have an eye on retirement, with two adult children who moved out of the family home, the idea was to create a retreat that would bring the family together on weekends and over the summer months.</p>
<p><a href="http://www.mudoffice.com.au/">MUD OFFICE</a> helped to finish off a beautifully executed home by providing the landscape that flows around the house.</p>
```

When i Check the Output in the front End:

```
<p>From The Architect - The Split House negotiates a complex range of conditions typical of emerging coastal developments. New houses for ‘downsizers’ in a suburban mode, paved driveways and letterboxes prevail, vying for the expansive views to Port Philip Bay, and backed by the relatively wild, coastal woodland of Mt Martha Public Park. The Split House provides a range of spatial relationships to its site and the broader territory that carefully balances the owners’ desire for privacy and engagement with their surrounds. The house comprises two relatively simple volumes linked by a splayed stair that also acts as a seating area for people to gather, listen to music, sit in the sun. Occupying separate levels that follow the natural contours of the site, the two pavilions provide a separation between the upper, main living/master bedroom zone and rumpus room/guest bedrooms below. Through the curation of windows and doors a range of direct and indirect connections to the landscape provide multiple opportunities for occupation throughout the year. Smaller elements, such as integrated seating, stairs and study nooks provide spaces for quiet contemplation, juxtaposed with larger communal areas for family and friends to come together.The award-winning house was designed for a couple who have an eye on retirement, with two adult children who moved out of the family home, the idea was to create a retreat that would bring the family together on weekends and over the summer months.
<a href="http://www.mudoffice.com.au/">MUD OFFICE</a>
 helped to finish off a beautifully executed home by providing the landscape that flows around the house.
</p>
```

It is not giving the ouput as written in the Wysiwg Editor of Advanced Custom Fields. Can anybody help me with finding out the issue with this?

Comment: I Think Your Plugin is not proper try with https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-create-wordpress-custom-fields

Answer (score 0):

You will get proper output when you try with apply_filters:

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_field_name', true )); ?>
```

Comment: Hi, I am not creating this field via code. It is through Plugin with that editor.There might be conflict with some data output, but i am unable to figure that out.